# Unity3D iOS Build Crashes on Launch with Error:Could not produce class with ID 30

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

I have successfully built my Unity3D project for iOS, but when I run the app on a device, it crashes immediately. The error message I'm getting is: "Could not produce class with ID 30. This could be caused by a class being stripped from the build even though it is needed. Try disabling 'Strip Engine Code' in Player Settings."

I have already tried disabling the 'Strip Engine Code' option in the Player Settings, but the crash persists. Additionally, I have attempted to prevent specific types from being stripped by adding configurations to the link.xml file. For example:

```
<assembly fullname="UnityEngine">  
    <type fullname="UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsSettings" preserve="all" />  
</assembly>
```

However, this has not resolved the issue.

I'm not sure what else to try. Can anyone suggest what might be causing the app to crash and how I can fix it? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

unity ：2022.3.8f1c1
xcode ：14.3.1
iphone : iphonex, 15.4

APP build and runs normally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.